# Why is this question an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833041/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-add-redis-to-etc-services) has 13 up votes. However, when reviewing this in Triage, there were a few comments below, suggesting that this might be better off on Code Golf. This looks like a question for code golf, and not necessarily Stack Overflow itself, it doesn't look like a question for here, it's not about algorithms or solving problems.

What bugged me about this was it was an audit. I tried commenting on it saying that they could request it to be migrated by raising a flag. It wouldn't let me, so I went to the question itself, finding out that this had 13 votes. Why is this question an audit, where there is discussion on whether it is a Code Golf question?

Comment: If anything, it should not go to Code Golf. It is not a programming contest, or a question about improving golfing skills.

Comment: But taken from the question itself: *while not mandatory, the solution's length (or lack of rather) is certainly an important part of its elegance (similarly for external dependencies [i.e. lack of these]); b) I/we assumed that /etc/services is sorted, but it would be interesting to see what happens when it isn't; c) assume that you have root privileges and be careful with that rm / -rf command.*

Comment: The comment was just a joke.  It was probably picked because it got a lot of flags.  Not too late to close it btw.

Comment: Ohhh. That makes sense. Should I flag with a custom flag with a request for migration?

Comment: @Zizouz212, Yes, you could, although mods are quite picky about what they migrate.

Comment: Ok, I raised the flag. At least it's to their attention, the question and the audit in the queue. :)

Comment: Meh, declined... :(